# Ruby on Rails - adding an attachment to a nested form. Not submitting / saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, simple-form

I have an app where there's a 'Gig' model, which is made up of many 'Songs'.
I want each song to have a song_file that the user must upload.

I've just installed the paperclip gem (with the intention of adding AWS shortly), however once I added the `<div class="col-md-4"><%= f.input :song_file, as: :file %></div>`, the 'submit' button on the Gig _form is no longer working.

If I don't attach a file, the 'Submit' works fine and the 'Song' updates. As soon as I select a file for upload though, clicking the button does nothing.

I have no idea what I've done to bork it... any help would be much appreciated!

Working on C9.io

**Gems**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'devise'
etc...
```

**Gig/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h2>Define the gig</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(@gig) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :gig_name %>
    <%= f.input :gig_date, class: "input-append date form_datetime" %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h2>Add the songs</h2>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for(:songs) do |song| %>
      <%= render 'song_fields', :f => song %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Another Song', f, :songs, class: "btn btn-primary col-md-8 col-md-offset-4" %>
    </div>
    <br>
    </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn-primary col-md-12" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**Gig/_song_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><%= f.input :name %></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><%= f.input :singfile %></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><%= f.input :song_file, as: :file %></div>

    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Song", f, class: "btn btn-default btn-danger col-md-4"  %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Gig_Controller params**

```
def gig_params
      params.require(:gig).permit(:gig_name, :gig_date, songs_attributes: [:id, :name, :singfile, :song_file ])
    end
```

**Gig Model**

```
class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :songs

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :songs, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Song Model**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
  has_attached_file :song_file
end
```

Comment: Please post the generated hash of params when you are submitting the form.

Comment: I'm assuming you are seeing this behavior whether you have provided a file or not in your testing?

Comment: @Pavan I don't think there is anything generated... the 'Submit' just ceases working as soon as I put the file upload field into the form. 

I also just checked and the 'Submit' button ceases to work, only when I attempt to attach a file.

Answer (score 0):

I solving this adding `:html => { :multipart => true }` in the form for

```
`<%= f.simple_fields_for(:songs), :html => { :multipart => true }` do |song| %>
   <%= render 'song_fields', :f => song %>
 <% end %>`
```